# attached component does not work AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hey when I tried to add a new component to my demo, angular just stop working. 
What can I do wrong with joining a new component?

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/LOeBra?editors=1010

**EDIT**

https://plnkr.co/edit/yL4Dg1bIPVLMX3CswEOJ?p=preview
Problem is how can I add subcomponent

```
<search></search>
```

Look file top-menu-module.js can u explain me??

Comment: You're initializing the ChildCcmponent variable **after** you pass it to component(). So it's undefined. Open the console, and read the error message.

Comment: thanks a lot,  can u look on edit??

Comment: When defiing the search component, don't recreate the top-menu module. Replace `.module('app.top-menu', [])`, which creates a module, by `.module('app.top-menu')`, which gets a reference to the already created module. https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/api/ng/function/angular.module